# Conditional expectation $E[(X+Y)^2|=]$, independents X and Y

Tags: conditional-expectation, solution-verification

X e Y, random independent variables with mean zero and equal variances. If $Z=X+Y,$ I need to find $E[Z^2|=]$ for any x value in the defined conditional distribution.

---

Is this correct?

$$E[(+)^2|=]=E[^2|=]+E[Y^2|=]+E[2XY|=]=$$
$$=x^2+E[Y^2|=]+2xE[Y]=x^2+E[Y^2]$$

Comment: This is correct. If you denote $\sigma^2=Var(X)=Var(Y)$, then since $E(X)=E(Y)=0$, it follows that $E(Y^2)=\sigma^2$.

Comment: True! Thank you so much.